# Java enum, integer and string together define?

Tags: java, enums, integer

I want to define string and integer together but it gives errors.

```
public class Card {
    Rank rank;
    Suit suit;
    public Card(Rank rank, Suit suit){
        this.rank=rank;
        this.suit=suit;
    }
    public enum Rank { Ace, 9, Queen, King } //and other suits
}
```

The error is a syntax error on token 9, delete this token.

Comment: i don't think you can put integer as an enum value

Comment: A integer is not a valid variable name in Java!

Answer (score 10):

In declaring enum in Java `{ Ace, 9,  Queen, King }` these are not strings and integers. **These are actual objects of enum.**

You can do this:

```
 public enum Rank { 
     Ace(13), 
     Nine(8),
     //etc
     ;

     private int rank;

     Rank(int rank) {
         this.rank = rank;
     }

     public int getRank() { 
         return rank;
     }
 }
```

Comment: `enum  Rank { Ace, 9,  Queen, King };` gives an error like this `Syntax error on token "9", Identifier expected` ....i cannot understand why?

Comment: @AnudeepSamaiya Because 9 is not an valid variable name. You cannot name your variables 9, enum constants also act like a variable. They even may be, in effect, variables.

Answer (score 9):

The things inside `enum`s are *identifiers*, names of static final (constant) objects that'll be created. So, you can't use an int for naming an object.

`enum`s allow you to place fields for each entry:

```
public static enum Suit {HEART,DIAMOND,SPADE,CLUB}

public static enum Cards {
    ACE_OF_HEART(Suit.HEART,14), QUEEN_OF_SPADE(Suit.SPADE,13) /* etc etc*/;

    private final Suit mSuit;
    private final int mRank;

    private Cards(Suit suit, int rank) {
        assert rank >= 2 && rank <= 14;
        mSuit = suit;
        mRank = rank;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() {
        return mSuit;
    }

    public int getRank() {
        return mRank;
    }
}
```

You really don't want to code all 52 cards this way. You can model it another way:

Suite:

```
public static enum Suit { SPADE, HEART, DIAMOND, CLUB};
```

Class with some popular ranks as named constants:

```
public class Card{

  public static final int ACE = 14;
  public static final int QUEEN = 13;
  public static final int KING = 12;
  public static final int JACK = 11;

  private final int mRank;
  private final Suite mSuit;

  public Card(Suite s, int r){
    this.mSuit = s;

    if(r < 2 || r > 14){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such card with rank: "+r);
    }    

    this.mRank = r;
  }

  public Suit getSuit() {
        return mSuit;
    }

    public int getRank() {
        return mRank;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot start an enum field with a number. Try using `NINE`.

Answer (score 2):

Java naming rules say you cannot start variables, class names ect... with numbers.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
public enum Rank    { Ace, Jack,  Queen, King }//and other suits
```

instead of your enum

the problem is that if you could have put number as enum value then the compiler won't know, when someone write "9" it he meant the number or the enum. so java, as almost every language, won't allow this kind of enum value

Comment: @DuncanJones copy paste from the code that worked that went wrong. fixed and added information

Comment: @DuncanJones, i know. thank you btw, i always try to leave at the very least a good working answer

Answer (score 1):

U cannot use integers inside enum like this. Please go through this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html